Sending JSON Data between devices using Rosbridge_Websocket
PC1 (sender) has pure Ubuntu OS (22.04).
PC2 (receiver) has Ubuntu 22.04 running on VM in W11.
I need to send JSON (data.json) data from PC1 to PC2 using rosbridge_websocket. I connected both PCs via LAN. To send a sensor data via ROS2 Humble and rosbridge, I created a node but without directing the rosbridge port(9090), rosbridge couldn't find the topic. How can I connect to rosbridge from the publisher and subscribe to it in an HTML file on the PC2? Any comments?
Connected to rosbridge_server like this:
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
ros2 launch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket_launch.xml

